# VisualStudio 2017 15.7.0 can't use DataTips in debug mode of WebForm

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I update to VS 15.7.0 this morning. In WSP: webform, when I use debug and hover over variagles, no DataTip popup, sadly...

I test in .ASPX, .ASHX, .CS ... all won't work.

But I open a new console project to test, that's totally fine.

Any suggestion? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After update to 15.7.1 this morning, BUG terminated.